# What's the difference between "dressing" and "seasoning" when it comes to the ingredients of cooking?

Tags: meaning, usage

I'm often confused with the two words when expressing the ingredients that adjust flavor of dishes, such as garlic, vinegar, basil, curry... Which are dressings and which are seasonings? And how to classify them? or it's just different expression of British English and American English?

Answer (score 2):

[Dressing](http://oaadonline.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/dressing) (or *salad dressing*) means, "a thin sauce used to add flavor to salads." That sauce is generally made with oil, vinegar, salt, and pepper, but it could also include mayonnaise or other ingredients.
[Seasoning](http://oaadonline.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/seasoning) is used to mean what is used to add flavor to food, generally salt and pepper.

In North American English, *dressing* could also be used as synonym of [stuffing](http://oaadonline.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/stuffing).